# Problema al entrar en un if

Tags: java, condiciones

Estoy creando un Frame en el que inserto un par de laminas con texto y 2 JCheckBox para modificar el tipo del texto y 4 JRadioButton para modificar el tamaño.
Para dicha accion creé 2 clases que implementan ActionListener.
El problema esta en el ultimo ActionListener (que es el que setea si va en negrita o en cursiva). Hice un sistema de 4 if para determinar el objeto que desencadeno el evento y también saber si fue por seleccionarse o deseleccionarse. La cuestión es que el programa entra en los 4 `if`, independientemente de quien haya llamado al evento.
Para comprobarlo, dentro de cada `if` puse un `System.out.println("ERROR");` para poder ver que `if` se ejecutaba y resulta qeu se ejecutan los 4.

Si alguien puede aclararme en que me equivoqué le estaría muy agradecido.
Espero no haber sido demasiado extenso con la explicación del problema.
Dejo el código y las lineas en cuestión están comentadas

```
package Swing;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MarcoJRadioButton_II_94 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MarcoJRadioButton mimarco=new MarcoJRadioButton();
        mimarco.setVisible(true);

    }
}
class MarcoJRadioButton extends JFrame{

    public MarcoJRadioButton(){
        setSize(500, 350);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        LaminaJRadioButton lamina=new LaminaJRadioButton();
        add(lamina);
    }
}
class LaminaJRadioButton extends JPanel{

    public LaminaJRadioButton(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        texto=new JLabel("En un canal de la Mancha cuyo nombre...");
        //texto.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        a=0;
        tama=12;
        add(texto);
        laminaRadioButtons=new JPanel();
        add(laminaRadioButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        grupoTamagno=new ButtonGroup();
        grupoTipo=new ButtonGroup();
        BotonTamagno("Pequeño", false, 10);
        BotonTamagno("Mediano", true, 12);
        BotonTamagno("Grande", false, 18);
        BotonTamagno("Muy grande", false, 24);
        laminaTipo=new JPanel();
        add(laminaTipo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        BotonTipo("Cursiva", false, 2);
        BotonTipo("Negrita", false, 1);
        set_a(0, 12);


    }
    public void set_a(int b, int t){
        texto.setFont(new Font("Serif", b, t));
    }
    public void BotonTamagno(String nombre, boolean estado, final int tamagno){
        JRadioButton boton=new JRadioButton(nombre, estado);
        grupoTamagno.add(boton);
        laminaRadioButtons.add(boton);
        boton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tama=tamagno;
                set_a(a, tama);
            }
        });
    }
    public void BotonTipo(String nombre, boolean estado, int tipo){
        JCheckBox boton=new JCheckBox(nombre, estado);
        //grupoTipo.add(boton);
        laminaTipo.add(boton);
        boton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // AQUI ES DONDE ESTA EL PROBLEMA, entra siempre a lso 4 if
                if(tipo==2 && boton.isSelected()) a=2+n; c=2; System.out.println("ERROR 1");
                if(tipo==2 && !boton.isSelected()) a=0+n; c=0; System.out.println("ERROR 2");
                if(tipo==1 && boton.isSelected()) a=1+c; n=1; System.out.println("ERROR 3");
                if(tipo==1 && !boton.isSelected()) a=0+c; n=0; System.out.println("ERROR 4");

                set_a(a, tama);
                System.out.println("a: "+a);
                System.out.println("c: "+c);
                System.out.println("n: "+n);

            }
        }); 
    }
    private int a, c=0, n=0, tama;
    private JLabel texto;
    private JPanel laminaRadioButtons, laminaTipo;
    private ButtonGroup grupoTamagno, grupoTipo;
}
```

Comment: A modo de recomendación te diría que cuando vayas a usar mas de 2 o 3 if seguidos hagas un switch case, es mas cómodo de leer y en términos generales mejor. Si no sabes como se hace mira [este](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_switch.asp) enlace donde lo explican bien

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Al escribir una pregunta, conviene centrarse en el problema que tienes y no escribir todo el programa; muchas veces al hacer un [mcve] verás tú mismo cuál es el problema y, si no, harás más fácil que alguien lo vea y te dé una respuesta.

Answer (score 5):

En cada una de estas líneas además del `if` hay 3 instrucciones:

```
if(tipo==2 && boton.isSelected()) a=2+n; c=2; System.out.println("ERROR 1");
if(tipo==2 && !boton.isSelected()) a=0+n; c=0; System.out.println("ERROR 2");
if(tipo==1 && boton.isSelected()) a=1+c; n=1; System.out.println("ERROR 3");
if(tipo==1 && !boton.isSelected()) a=0+c; n=0; System.out.println("ERROR 4");
```

Lo anterior equivale a hacer lo siguiente:

```
if(tipo==2 && boton.isSelected()) {
    a = 2 + n;
}
c=2;
System.out.println("ERROR 1");

if(tipo==2 && !boton.isSelected()) {
    a = 0 + n;
}
c=0;
System.out.println("ERROR 2");

if(tipo==1 && boton.isSelected()) {
    a = 1 + c;
}
n=1;
System.out.println("ERROR 3");

if(tipo==1 && !boton.isSelected()) {
    a = 0 + c;
}
n=0;
System.out.println("ERROR 4");
```

En Java puedes omitir las llaves de un `if` si el bloque de código consta de solamente una instrucción. Por lo tanto al omitirlos, el `if` solamente aplica para la primera instrucción de las 3.

Comment: Moraleja: usa **siempre** llaves en las estructuras de control.

Comment: Anda, es verdad!!
Cometi un herror de novato (que es lo que soy), olvide que solo se pueden omitir las llaves del if si hay solo una linea de codigo. 
Ya coregi la sintaxis y funciona perfectamente.
Muchisimas gracias!!